# how to call superclass parameterized constructor by subclass?

Tags: java

Why i am getting error in the starting of Employee constructor that cannot find symbol 
constuctor Person?

```
class Person {
    String name = "noname";

    Person(String nm) {
        name = nm;
    }
}

class Employee extends Person {
    String empID = "0000";

    Employee(String eid) {// error
        empID = eid;
    }
}

public class EmployeeTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Employee e1 = new Employee("4321");
        System.out.println(e1.empID);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `super` keyword is your friend. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html

Answer (score 6):

You need to call

```
super(name);
```

as the first statement of the constuctor `Employee` as the compiler will otherwise implicitly call the no-argument constructor for `Person` which doesnt exist

where `name` is an added argument to `Employee`

```
Employee(String eid, String name) {
    super(name);
    empID = eid;
}
```

Take a look at example [8.2-1 from the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#d5e9887) which shows how a similar example fails in the absence of an explicit `super` method call.

Comment: This won't be the right thing to do if the "employee id" is not the same thing as the person's name.  Which means, this answer is _probably_ (but not necessarily) wrong.

Answer (score 2):

When you create an employee, you'll need to specify both a name and an employee id - since every employee is a person, and every person needs a name.  The constructor for `Employee` should probably look like this.

```
public Employee(String eid, String name) {
    super(name);
    empID=eid;
}
```

The `super` line specifies how to call the superclass's constructor.  It needs to be in there because there's no constructor for the superclass without parameters.  A superclass constructor must be called, there's only one available constructor, and that constructor needs the `name` argument to be specified.

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this to get your program to work:

```
class Person {
    String name = "noname";
    Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class Employee extends Person {
    String empID = "0000";

    Employee(String empID , String name) {
        super(name);
        this.empID = empID;
    }
}

public class EmployeeTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Employee e1 = new Employee("4321" , "Ramesh");
        System.out.println(e1.empID);
        System.out.println(e1.name);
    }
}
```

I have a couple of points to add.

1. It is always a good habit to make your data member `private`. If you want to access those members outside the class, use getters and setters. ( `getName()`, `setName()` etc. )
2. Your constructors ( `Person()` and `Employee()` ) HAVE to be defined if you want to creating an object without using parameterized constructor. NO default contstructor will be provided for you if you want to instantiate using a non-parameterized constructor. So do THIS whenever you are using a parameterized constructor as a good habit:

   ```
   class Person {
       private String name = "noname";
       Person() {}
       Person(String name) {
           this.name = name;
       }
       public String getName() {
           return this.name;
       }
       public void setName(String name) {
           this.name = name;
       }
   }


   class Employee extends Person {
       private String empID = "0000";
       Employee() {}
       Employee(String empID,String name) {
           this.empID = empID;
       }
       public String getEmpID() {
           return this.empID;
       }
       public void setName(String empID) {
           this.empID = empID;
       }
   }
   ```